# have line printed on same line after host name - Manipulating text scripting linux bash

Tags: bash, ssh, sed, awk

I produce this /temp/test file  by running this command

```
for i in `cat /tmp/hosts` ;
do ssh $i -t "echo $i;sudo /usr/sbin/ethtool -S eth1 | grep   discards";
done > /tmp/test
```

This is he output of the command that is piped into test /tmp/test file

```
yyyx01
     rx_ftq_discards: 0
     rx_discards: 0
     rx_fw_discards: 0
yyyx02
     rx_ftq_discards: 0
     rx_discards: 0
     rx_fw_discards: 45
yyyx03
     rx_ftq_discards: 0
     rx_discards: 0
     rx_fw_discards: 46
yyyx04
     rx_ftq_discards: 0
     rx_discards: 0
     rx_fw_discards: 47
yyyx05
     rx_ftq_discards: 0
     rx_discards: 0
     rx_fw_discards: 34022
```

I need the output to appear as follow so I can pull it in to excel sheet

```
yyyx01   0   0  0  0
yyyx02   0   0  0  45
yyyx03   0   0  0  46
yyyx04   0   0  0  47
```

Can anyone help please with the code to achieve this?  I can dump the output into a temp file and then manipulate it with a command if it cannot be done via the SSH command line

Thanking you in advance

Comment: I figured that my two sample files are different the one you copy and paste from here is ASCII with CRLF line termination and the other is just a ASCII text file. so that is why most of the commands on this page are not working on my sample .. I guess .. Does anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: so after I convered my file to unix the comnands work .. Not sure how to give everyone a thumbs up!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", $NF, (NR%4 ? OFS : ORS)}' file
yyyx01 0 0 0
yyyx02 0 0 45
yyyx03 0 0 46
yyyx04 0 0 47
yyyx05 0 0 34022
```

If you want to use tabs or commas or anything instead of a blank char between fields, just set OFS:

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '{printf "%s%s", $NF, (NR%4 ? OFS : ORS)}' file
yyyx01,0,0,0
yyyx02,0,0,45
yyyx03,0,0,46
yyyx04,0,0,47
yyyx05,0,0,34022

$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{printf "%s%s", $NF, (NR%4 ? OFS : ORS)}' file
yyyx01  0       0       0
yyyx02  0       0       45
yyyx03  0       0       46
yyyx04  0       0       47
yyyx05  0       0       34022
```

Comment: Hi Ed - Thanks for ur reply. Unfortunately none of the commands works for me.. I'm getting this

Comment: 0rm01
 21552
 550832
 82544
 34022
 48915

Comment: Sorry your command works as well. with the sample text I have provided .. Not sure why it's not working with my output file on linux host

Comment: just looked at my sample file on my hosts .. the only difference is the host names that are different form one another.. Otherwise they are almost identical No extra line or special characters. The host names have different length and characters in the. That's the only diffrence

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -F':' 'NF==1{if (NR>1) print ""; printf "%s", $1; next}
           NF==2{printf "%s%s", OFS, $NF} END{print ""}' file
yyyx01  0  0  0
yyyx02  0  0  45
yyyx03  0  0  46
yyyx04  0  0  47
yyyx05  0  0  34022
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are you getting different output?

Comment: Yes getting totally different output . The only thing different in my source file  are the name of the hosts . They are no of equal length . So the output is totally is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ssh $i -t <<END
out=\$(sudo /usr/sbin/ethtool -S eth1 | grep discards | grep -o '[0-9]\\+\$')
echo $i \$out
END
```

Comment: Hi Glenn .. This is not working at all . it's the syntax

Comment: Then I would use Ed Morton's answer.

Comment: ok thanks those are not working for me either. Going to copy and paste the exact text I have put here and try again

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed '/^[^ ]/{N;s/[ ]/\t0/;N;N;s/\n//g;s/[^ ]*://g}' input
```

*Gives:*

```
yyyx01  0     0      0      0
yyyx02  0     0      0      45
yyyx03  0     0      0      46
yyyx04  0     0      0      47
yyyx05  0     0      0      34022
```

Comment: Hi .. Not working at all. Not sure why none of these commands are working

Comment: Sorry it does work with the sample text I have posted but not with the sample text I have in my linux host. Not sure why

Comment: just looked at my sample file on my hosts .. the only difference is the host names that are different form one another.. Otherwise they are almost identical No extra line or special characters. The host names have different length and characters in the. That's the only diffrence